# Passing value from one class to another

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios

I am newbie to Objective C.
I want to pass the value of the text field from one screen to other screen and want to display it in 2nd screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Way 1:

- If its key data that is needed application wise store it in [app delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051842/simple-delegate-example)

Way 2:

- When you switch UI , you create new object of secondView's controller use setter getters to set it in second controller.

**For example:**

```
WelcomeView *welcome= [[WelcomeView alloc] initWithFrame: rect];
[welcome setParam:someParam];
[mainView addSubview: welcome];
```

- [Detailed How to switch the views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910994/view-controllers-how-to-switch-between-views-programmatically)

Comment: thanks for the reply.But can u please elobrate as i m newbie to xcode so just not having much idea.I want to do it thought way 2 by using geter seter method

Comment: check update. I am not sure about syntax at `setParam` please verify it