# ios simulate press done/return

Tags: objective-c, keypress, simulate

I dont want to hide keyboard, but simulate tapping done/return key type, so it will call one of my functions.

`UITextFieldInputTraits`?

I appreciate if you could direct me in right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UITextField delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
  [self myFoo];
  return NO;
}
```

if you need to simulate tapping return call this function like:

```
[self textFieldShouldReturn:nil];
```

Comment: It says MainViewController (which is a UIViewController) ma not resond to your latter function.

Comment: Because your view controller needs to conform to that protocol first. Read about what the delegation is from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051842/simple-delegate-example You might also want to read a few tutorials on adopting your classes to delegation protocols. This one for example http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/site/2011/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development