# Delegate - How to Use?

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates

I think I understand the logic behind a delegate. I got more the problem to use it. How many steps are involved? Do I have to use existing delegates? Or can I use my one ones?

In my example I got the AppDelegate that created many views (Objects / View Controllers) of the same type. Each view should somehow call a method on the AppDelegate to close itself. This would happen when a button within the view is touched. The method call would include the reference of the view (self).

So far I know  from other languages responders, event listeners and so on. They are so simple to use.

Can anybody help me. I just found massive examples with a lot of code in the web. It can't be that hard to just call a parent in Objective C.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051842/simple-delegate-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use for this the `NSNotificationCenter`

in you **AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
...
...
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(buttonPushed:) name:@"ButtonPushedNotification" object:nil];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
...
...
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

this is the selector it will be called when the notification happens (we are still in the **AppDelegate.m**)

```
- (void)buttonPushed:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSLog(@"the button pushed...");
}
```

and in the **ViewController.m** when the button pushed (inside the method), you should post a notification like this:

```
{
...
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ButtonPushedNotification" object:nil];
...
}
```

Comment: Hi Holex.. I really like this idea... to me it really looks like a event pattern model I learned years ago in a framework called Swi, which was used to construct complex as3/flex mvc based projects. Idea was to push messages to a controller (singleton) that would route tasks and jobs between objects. Really light and powerful solution.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to get what you want is to just start with one view. Then, have each other view be presented modally. When the button in the view is pressed do

`[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

And here's something I made a while ago when I was starting iPhone development that might help you with delegates

```
Delegates

//In parent .m file:
//assign the delegate
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueName"])
    {
        childController *foo = segue.destinationViewController;
        foo.delegate = self;
    }

}

//implement protocol method(s):
- (void) methodName:(dataType*) dataName
{
    //An example of what you could do if your data was an NSDate
    buttonLabel.titleLabel.text = [[date description] substringToIndex:10];
}

//In parent .h file:
//import child header
#import "ChildName.h"

//indicate conformity with protocol
@interface ParentName : UIViewController <ChildNameDelegate>

//In child .h file
//declare protocol
@protocol ChildNameDelegate
- (void) methodName:(dataType*) dataName;
@end

//declare delegate
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) id<ChildNameDelegate> delegate;


//In child .m file
//synthesize delegate
@synthesize delegate; 

//use method
- (IBAction)actionName:(id)sender 
{
    [delegate methodName:assignedData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own:

In MyView1.h:

```
@class MyView1;

@protocol MyView1Delegate <NSObject>

- (void)closeMyView1:(MyView1 *)myView1;

@end

@interface MyView1 : NSObject
{
    id<MyView1Delegate> _delegate;
}

@property (assign, nonatomic, readwrite) id<MyView1Delegate> delegate;

...

@end
```

In MyView1.m:

```
@interface MyView1

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

...

// The method that tells the delegate to close me
- (void)closeMe
{
    ....
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(closeMyView1:)])
    {
        [_delegate closeMyView1:self];
    }
}

@end
```

In AppDelegate.h:

```
#import "MyView1.h"

@interface AppDelegate <MyView1Delegate>
{
    MyView1 *_myView1;
}

...

@end
```

In AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)someCreateViewMethod
{
    _myView1 = [[MyView1 alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 200)];
    [_myView1 setDelegate:self];
    ...
}
```