# From Some Class Call Method In View Controller Class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, c, cocoa-touch

Okay so let's say I have class A...

**CLASS A** has a method that gets called as soon as the user makes an in app purchase.

```
-(void) didMakePurchase { ...  }
```

**(VIEW CONTROLLER) CLASS B** is the View Controller for the current scene. Inside class B I have a function that creates a UIAlertView that basically thanks the user for making the purchase.

```
-(void) createAlertViewAfterSuccessfulPurchase {  ...create UIAlertView... }
```

**Goal/Problem:** I want to be able to call the createAlertViewAfterSuccessfulPurchase method inside the didMakePuchase method which is in Class B.

**What I've Tried:** I tried importing class A and creating an object of Class B in Class A just so I could call that method, but it didn't work (my guess is because Class B is a view controller).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Make Class B a delegate of Class A and then do:

```
[myDelegate createAlertViewAfterSuccessfulPurchase:myParams]
```

To declare the delegate:

```
In class A:

.h

@protocol myProtocol;

@interface ClassA : UIView
{

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<myProtocol> delegate;

@protocol myProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)createAlertViewAfterSuccessfulPurchase;

@end

.m

self.delegate = classBInstance.

to call:

[delegate createAlertViewAfterSuccessfulPurchase]

in Class B:

.h

@interface ClassB : NSObject <myProtocol>

.m

implementation of:

-(void) createAlertViewAfterSuccessfulPurchase {  ...create UIAlertView... }
```

Comment: How would I make class B a delegate of Class A?

Comment: I got it all working, but the method doesn't get called... But I get no errors...

Comment: @TheMan messaged send to nil do not cause error in obj-c, so check that your delegate has been set and is not nil before calling your method.

Comment: +1 I prefer delegates to provide handlers that must be used to process events, rather than a notification which is a one-to-many broadcast.

Answer (score 2):

Post an `NSNotification` in class A, and in class B add an observer to this notification

Answer (score 0):

check this solution, for this the simplest way is to use the `NSNotificationCenter`.

The current example is here *(don't let the title confuses you, it is not about the delegates)*

[Delegate - How to Use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229830/delegate-how-to-use/11230990#11230990)

but if there is connection between the two classes, I mean, your **Class B** creates the **Class A**, there is another way too, because you can also use the blocks in that case like this:

in your **ClassB.m** file:

```
- (void)startPurchase {
    [classAinstance didMakePurchaseWithFinishedBlock:^{
        UIAlertView *_alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [_alertView show];
    }];
}
```

in your **ClassA.m** file:

```
-(void) didMakePurchaseWithFinishedBlock:(void (^)())finishedBlock { 
    ...

    finishedBlock();
}
```